# Celery task getting SoftTimeLimitExceeded calling API

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I have two tasks, where I need to call two different API to send a SMS and an email.

## views.py

```
def ...:
    ...
    send_payment_failed_sms.delay(payment_log.id, 1)
    task_send_booking_failed_email(payment_log.id, 1)
```

But I always get the folowing error on the task to send SMS, but the task sending email works fine:

```
[2018-07-12 20:47:03,519: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: payments.tasks.send_payment_failed_sms[ac4f1c2a-f09d-4e79-89c9-dfe1ab26b25d]  
[2018-07-12 20:47:18,548: WARNING/MainProcess] Soft time limit (15s) exceeded for payments.tasks.send_payment_failed_sms[ac4f1c2a-f09d-4e79-89c9-dfe1ab26b25d]
[2018-07-12 20:47:18,563: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] on_failure
[2018-07-12 20:47:18,563: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] ac4f1c2a-f09d-4e79-89c9-dfe1ab26b25d
[2018-07-12 20:47:18,564: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 'ac4f1c2a-f09d-4e79-89c9-dfe1ab26b25d' failed: SoftTimeLimitExceeded()
[2018-07-12 20:47:18,564: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task payments.tasks.send_payment_failed_sms[ac4f1c2a-f09d-4e79-89c9-dfe1ab26b25d] raised unexpected: SoftTimeLimitExceeded()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
billiard.exceptions.SoftTimeLimitExceeded: SoftTimeLimitExceeded()
```

## tasks.py

```
@shared_task(bind=True, base=MyBaseClassForTask, max_retries=5, default_retry_delay=1 * 60, soft_time_limit=15,
             time_limit=30)
def send_payment_failed_sms(self, payment_id, reason):

    try:
        try:
            payload = ""
            headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            url = 'https://sms-site.com/apikey=' + api_key + '&to=%s&var1=%s' % (
                mobile, payment_log.id
            )
            response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
            response = response.json()

            if response['Status'] == 'Success':
                print('Sent message'), response['Details']
            else:
                print('Error:', response['Details'])

        except ConnectionError as exc:
            print('connection error @ failed sms')
            raise self.retry(exc=exc)

    except PaymentLog.DoesNotExist:
        ...
```

Also, it does not retry for the max_retries, i.e., 5 times. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Or is there any better way to define a task while calling an API?

Comment: Is the PaymentLog error thrown? Are any of the prints in the ConnecitonError try block shown?

Comment: @grrrrrr No, they not thrown.

Comment: are you able to get that exact request to go through outside of the celery task? The empty payload stands out to me as possibly problematic. You could also try setting timeout for the request to see if that is the issue http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts

Answer (score 7):

you hve `soft_time_limit=15 seconds`, after this time celery raise `SoftTimeLimitExceeded` this exeption allow you to do cleanup inside your task

```
from celery.exceptions import SoftTimeLimitExceeded

@celery.task(soft_time_limit=15, time_limit=20)
def mytask():
    try:
        return do_work()
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        cleanup_in_a_hurry()
```

Comment: the related docs https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-soft-time-limit

Comment: **cleanup_in_a_hurry()** is undefined for me, How to handle this?

Comment: it function written by you that could roll back or do another clean up stuff if you need any